# anchor tag href is not working in firefox but works fine in chrome

Tags: angular, firefox, click, anchor, href

I have below code to open the link in a new tab. The code works fine Chrome browser but doesnt work in Firefox, After searching in google I found that anchor tag should not be directly enclosed inside a button , so I placed a div tag to enclose the anchor tag and it still doesnt work.

```
<button type="button" (click)="getDirection(m.geometry.location.lat,m.geometry.location.lng)"  class="waves-effect waves-light btn directions"> 
         <div>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={{srcOriginLat}},{{srcOriginLng}}&destination={{srcDestinationLat}},{{srcDestinationLng}}&travelmode=driving" target='_blank'>{{'directions' | translate}} </a>
         </div>  
         </button>
```

Comment: The below answer is the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the button tag and placed the href insdie the div directly and it works fine.

```
 <div (click)="getDirection(m.geometry.location.lat,m.geometry.location.lng)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn directions">
              <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={{srcOriginLat}},{{srcOriginLng}}&destination={{srcDestinationLat}},{{srcDestinationLng}}&travelmode=driving"
                target='_blank'>{{'directions' | translate}} </a>
            </div>
```